# fetching by foreign key elements in appengine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have three database tables:

```
class Book(bd.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    pub_time = db.DateTimeProperty()
    subject = db.StringProperty()

class Author(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    age = db.IntegerProperty()

class Match(db.Model):
    bk = ReferenceProperty(Book, collection_name='book')
    ath = ReferenceProperty(Author, collection_name='books_written')
```

**Problem:** I want to filter books written by an author `ATH`, on subject `SUB`

**My Approach:**

```
class BookSearch(webapp2.requestHandler):
    def post(self):
        b = Books.all().filter("subject =", 'SUB')
        a = Author.all().filter("name =", "ATH")
        ret = Match.all().filter("bk =", b). filter("ath =", a)
        self.response.out.write(ret.count())
```

But this does not work and i get an error:

```
BadValueError: Unsupported type for property  : <class 'google.appengine.ext.db.Query'>
```

Comment: Would it not be just much simpler to add a `author = ReferenceProperty(Author)` to your Book model? So that later you can just do a `Book.all().filter("subject", 'SUB').filter("author", author_key).fetch()` ?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but, sorry @alex but why do you forget a book can have multiple authors? and an author can write multiple books.

Comment: Right, sorry, didn't see catch that. But, it's simple to just use [ListProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListProperty) then: `authors = ListProperty(Key)`. The query would be identical I guess.

Comment: BTW, I highly recommend using new library, NDB, which would allow you to do something like `author = KeyProperty('Author', repeated=True)`

Comment: this is the last thing i want to implement in my project, there has been so many things that are done and prepopultated i would probably give that a look in my next project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a and b are queries and not entities. you need to get the entity first before you can use it as filter in another query:

```
class BookSearch(webapp2.requestHandler):
    def post(self):
        b = Books.all().filter("subject =", 'SUB').get()
        a = Author.all().filter("name =", "ATH").get()
        ret = Match.all().filter("bk =", b).filter("ath =", a)
        self.response.out.write(ret.count())
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it saved my ass!! i was thinking of quitting the project !!

Comment: This will fetch the first book on subject SUB and attempt to match it to the author with that name, rather than showing all books by that subject. To do that, the OP needs to get rid of the `Match` kind and make authors a listproperty on book, then filter on that.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `bk IN` instead of `bk =` as the results in `b` can be more than one single value.

Try this:

```
ret = Match.all().filter("bk IN", b). filter("ath IN", a)
```

Docs are over here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_filter

Comment: haven't tried it yet, but it might work, one more question, say i am sure there is only one author with name ATH how do i write using `get` instead of `filter`.

Comment: You cant. You can only `get` if you know the key.

Comment: sorry, but the above solution does not work, with in there should always be a list item attached.

Comment: Then convert your values `b` and `a` to lists?